# How to check the record in a spooled file in Unix

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, wc, spool

I have to generate a csv file by creating a sql query(oracle) and then mail it to the user. Up to this part I have completed and is working fine.
But if there is any data returned in the spooled file, then only the mail need to be sent.
I am having little trouble because my mail query is in sql part, so for checking the file do I need to displace its order
 i.e. sqlplus -s user/pass <

mail logic(calling a procedure)
spool off;
exit
EOF

and how do I need to check the file size/count with which unix command s
or do I need to write this part in another sqlplus -s block and check with count of records

Can someone please suggest with the command or syntax for this as I am totally confused.Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you please clarify what you want and what you have tried or didn't work?

Comment: To count the number of lines in a unix file, use the command `wc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unix script and call the sqlplus script within and before u send the email you can check if the file size is NOT zero.